# Python: C for loop with two variables

Tags: python, c

I'm new to python. Is there a similar way to write this C for loop with 2 variables in python?

```
for (i = 0, j = 20; i != j; i++, j--) { ... }
```

Comment: Short answer: not really. `for` in python is for iterating over iterable things, and while `while` does the stuff with variables you'd like C-like `for` to do (notice how `for` in C is just a shortened `while`, thus quite redundant).

Answer (score 7):

Python 2.x

```
from itertools import izip, count
for i, j in izip(count(0, 1), count(20, -1)):
    if i == j: break
    # do stuff
```

Python 3.x:

```
from itertools import count
for i, j in zip(count(0, 1), count(20, -1)):
    if i == j: break
    # do stuff
```

This uses `itertools.count()`, an iterator that iterates from a certain starting point indefinitely:

> `itertools.count(start=0, step=1)`
>
> Make an iterator that returns evenly spaced values starting with `n`. Often used as an argument to `imap()` to generate consecutive data points. Also, used with `izip()` to add sequence numbers.

In Python 2.x you have to use `izip` because Py2K `zip` tries to create a list of all the results, as opposed to `izip` which returns an `iterator` over the results as they are obtained. Unfortunately we are dealing with infinite iterators here so `zip` won't work... this is probably a good point as to why `zip` has been changed to perform the role of `izip` in Py3K (`izip` no longer exists there).

If you are crazy about being *functional* you could even do this (but it looks ugly in my opinion since I have grown to hate `lambda`s):

```
from itertools import takewhile, izip, count
for i, j in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], izip(count(0, 1), count(20, -1))):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> i, j = 0, 10
>>> while i != j:
...     # Your code here:
...     print "i: %d j: %d" % (i, j)
...     i += 1
...     j -= 1
...
...
i: 0 j: 10
i: 1 j: 9
i: 2 j: 8
i: 3 j: 7
i: 4 j: 6
```

If you wonder why it's common to see `>>>` and `...` in code examples it's because people are using the python interpreter (a shell, if you'd like), or a wrapper around the python interpreter like [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/). I really recommend getting bpython for testing code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation you can use zip:

```
 lista = [1,2,3]
 listb = [4,5,6]
 for x,y in zip(lista, listb)
      print(x, y)
```

outputs:

```
 1 4
 2 5
 3 6
```

zip docs are here: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Also to go with what you were saying two numbers, you could do

```
for x,y in zip(range(0), range(10, 0, -1))
    if x == y:
        break
    # do stuff
```

This will give you both increasing and decreasing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip, but for the problem at hand, looping over the second variable isn't really necessary, and so a much simpler approach is warranted:

```
for i in range(10):
    j = 20 - i
    ⋮
```